# Trace shortcut in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, trace, shortcut

Is there any shortcut to generate trace statements from selected variable, like ctrl-shift-0 in flash develop?
E.g.: If I select myVar in the below line and press "DesiredShortcut":
var **myVar**=5;

I'd like to get:
var myVar=5;
**trace('myVar='+myVar);**

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using [Live Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html).

For Java IntelliJ IDEA already has `soutv` template that will generate

```
System.out.println("var=" + var);
```

after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

You can define your own templates to log via your favorite logging framework.

Comment: Yes, I've created live template for 'surround with' command: trace('$SELECTION$='+$SELECTION$); But now when I select a variable name (eg: var myVar:int=5 ), I get a trace generated in place of myVar, but it'll be better to get it on new line.

Comment: See how soutv template is defined, you don't need to use surround template.

Comment: Downvote for not actually providing the answer but just "hints" about looking into the "soutv" live template. The thing is, my version of IntelliJ doesn't have the "soutv" live template so I can't look it up. Could you please provide the actual live template code needed for what the OP actually asked for? Thank you.